# Uploading a file into a database and splitting the name or storing it in field

Tags: c#, import

We are implementing a system by which we are importing a file in a specific naming convention.

The naming convention is used so that we know who and what the file belongs to:  For example the convention is in

```
<customer number>-<season>-<supplier>-<extra name>.xml
```

When we read the file we parse it out to it's fields and then look these up in our database so that we can insert the file with the necessary *Foreign key* constraints.  For example our table that this inserts into is:

```
ID PK
CustomerId int (FK to customer table)
SeasonId (FK to season table)
SupplierId (FK to supplier table)
Name (<extra name> or filename)
OriginalFileName (This is an option we are considering)
```

This is ok however we are having a discussion in our team as to what should go into the name field.  When these files are viewed by the customer they want to see the **filename** of the file that was uploaded.

Hence we are discussing two options:

1. Store the filename into the Name field
2. Store only the  part of the file name in this field and rebuild the filename when required for display/download etc  We could also include another column that is the name of the file on upload.

We can't see to come to any agreement on the best approach.  Some of our points include:

**Option 1**

1. If we store just the name then we will need extra table joins and processing to build up the filename for display.
2. It won't be as easy to display on the view if we have to build up the filename each time

**Option 2**

1. Our parsing of the file is consistent in that every field is parsed into it's own column fields.
2. If we decide we want to change the way the filename is displayed i.e. just the name part then that's easier to do
3. It was considered that adding an extra field to contain the filename is pointless as we may as well just do option one if that was the case.

I'm not sure which option is the best.  The customer doesn't mind as long as the user sees the filename on display (they explictly want this name shown as a string even though there might be columns with this information).

Comment: You're asking for opinions. But the short answer/advice is to never store "compound" data in a single field. Always try to save datums (e.g. the filename's sub-components) in their own fields when at all possible. If you store compound data, you make it VERY hard for the DB to do its basic thing: relational data can't be related if it's not in a form that makes the relating easy.

Comment: Note that "It won't be as easy to display on the view if we have to build up the filename each time" sounds very shake reason...

Comment: @MarcB  I guess I am.  I was sort of asking for recommended approach to this problem as well from a generic point of view.  As your comment sort of addresses.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Yeah, but we couldn't think of a counter to that point.